# $_POST value from form select not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

On button click, I am using a ajax request to **POST** the **SELECT** data to my PHP page. For some reason I cannot get my PHP IF statements to evaluate as true. It is defaulting to the ELSE condition of **business_unit_brand = 3**. I tried echoing and print_r the $brand_bu variable to see what it holds with no luck.

Form:

```
    <select id="brand_bu" name="selected" class="form-control">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbu" type="button" tabindex="-1" action=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </span>
```

jQuery Ajax

```
$("#submitbu").click(function(event) {
console.log("Chose BU: " + $("#brand_bu").val());

$.ajax({

    url: "table.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'bu': $('#brand_bu').val()}),
    success: function(data){ console.dir(data); refreshTable(); },
    error: function(){alert("Something went wrong, please close the page and re-open.")}
}); });
```

PHP:

```
    $brand_bu = $_POST['bu'];

if ($brand_bu == "1"){
    $business_unit_brand = "1";
} else if ($brand_bu == "2"){
    $business_unit_brand = "2";
} else if ($brand_bu == "3"){
    $business_unit_brand = "3";
} else if ($brand_bu == "4"){
    $business_unit_brand = "4";
} else if ($brand_bu == "5"){
    $business_unit_brand = "5";
} else {
    $business_unit_brand = "3";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP expects the `POST` data to be in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, not JSON. `$.ajax` will automatically encode an object properly. So change to:

```
data: { bu: $("#brand_by").val() },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inspect element to see what your form posts or does not post. Click on the network tab and select the file name in question you should see the actions there.

```
Ctrl + Shift + i
```